# Tableau Title Either Display Individual State or 'United States' based on filter

Tags: dynamic, tableau-api

I have a graph which can be filtered to the state level by clicking on individual states.

The current title is coded as

```
<Sheet Name> : <ATTR(State)>
```

Which displays `Profit Over Time: New York` when in New York but `Profit Over Time: *` when no state is selected. I thought generating a calculated field and inserting that into the title might be the solution.

```
<Sheet Name> : <US or State>
```

The calculated field would be then to set the field equal to the first state in the list if the list only contains 1 state and "United States" otherwise.

```
IF COUNTD([State]) = 1 THEN [State][1]
ELSE "United States"
END
```

But I am having some difficulty with figuring out what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your [State] field is listed as an ATTR aggregation is causing the behavior you're seeing. Aggregating multiple strings always turns into *. Ideally you're able to simply change the filter on your worksheet to [State] with no ATTR aggregation then change your title to:

```
<Sheet Name> : <State>
```

The behavior will follow the filter: When "All" is selected, "All" will be displayed in your title.

Alternatively, I believe this calculated field will accomplish what yours was trying to do. It requires a table calculation that counts the states on the view and if there are 50, it assumes that all the states are showing and therefore should be called "United States" otherwise it shows only the one state. (Caveat: This does not work as well as my above suggestion if multiple states are selected.)

```
If WINDOW_COUNT(ATTR([State])) = 50 Then 'United States'
Else ATTR([State])
END
```

I'm sure there is a comparative LOD Calculation which would match the behavior above, however LODs operate differently with regards to order of operations on filtering. (LODs take place before filtering, Table Calculations take place after.) This order of operations on an LOD might make things a little more difficult and will be highly dependent on the structure of your data. It is possible though - and probably more efficient if done correctly.

Comment: Did this help/work for you? If so, please apply green check/tick for others to reference if facing the same issue. If you were able to solve on your own could you put the answer here? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `ATTR([State])` calculation in another, and use that calculation in your title:

```
IF ATTR([State]) = '*' THEN 'United States' ELSE ATTR([State]) END
```